# having a standard value when filling in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am using QGIS to collect field data and I wonder if it is possible to have a standard value apply to some of my attributes unless I say otherwise.

I fill my attribute table with several drop down menues ("name", "species", "quantity"..) but in most cases, some of these attributes are the same over and over again.
EDIT: I use Value Relations to populate the menues..

So I wonder if there is a way to either

a) always have, lets say the first entry of a specific drop down (attribute) pre-selected upon point creation

or

b) always fill the attribute table with a specific value if I select nothing. e.g. if I select nothing specific for the "quantity" attribute, fill the table with "1"

Comment: It sound like you're using a custom feature form. If so, you can assign a python init function to it in which you can specify the desired logic.

Comment: thank you for your reply. unfortunately no, I'm not using a custom form. I create the drop downs using "value relation or value map".. I just would like a standard value to be selected when I create a new point.

Comment: You could alternatively insert an x number of features without choosing a field (which results in a `NULL` value) and when done, use the **Field Calculator** to change all `NULL` values to your specified value. Not sure how to achieve this through the _Value Map_ options though.